# How can I overwrite data

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two datasets.
The 1st one is:

| Column_A |
| --- |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 1 |
| 6 |

and the 2nd one looks like this:

| Column_B | Column_C |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 2 | b |
| 3 | c |
| 4 | d |
| 5 | e |
| 6 | f |

How can I overwrite Column_A from the 1st data frame  with observation in Column_C if the value of Column_A is identical as the value of Column_B?

My result should look like this:

| Column_A |
| --- |
| c |
| d |
| a |
| f |

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `match` to find the index of column B that matches each entry in column A. Just subset column C by this.

```r
df1$Column_A <- df2$Column_C[match(df1$Column_A, df2$Column_B)]

df1
#>   Column_A
#> 1        c
#> 2        d
#> 3        a
#> 4        f
```

---

**Reproducible data**

```r
df1
#>   Column_A
#> 1        3
#> 2        4
#> 3        1
#> 4        6

df2
#>   Column_B Column_C
#> 1        1        a
#> 2        2        b
#> 3        3        c
#> 4        4        d
#> 5        5        e
#> 6        6        f
```